# Java mysql decimal ordering wrong

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I seem to have hit a bump. I'm creating an "Economy" system for a minecraft bukkit server.

I'm trying to order the table by "Richest" first, however the order being received is different. When I run the SQL through phpMyAdmin it is recieved in the correct order

[image]

[image]

```
public static HashMap<String, Double> topPlayers(String economyKey) {
    sql.build("SELECT b.balance, p.username FROM " + sql.prefix
            + "players p INNER JOIN " + sql.prefix + "balances b ON p.id=b.user_id WHERE economy_key=? ORDER BY b.balance DESC LIMIT 0,5");
    String[] params = { economyKey };

    ResultSet results = sql.executePreparedQuery(params);
    HashMap<String, Double> players = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    try {
        while (results.next()) {
            players.put(results.getString("username"), results.getDouble("balance"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return players;
}
```

Comment: You could easily switch to [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which maintains the insertion order, if your method returned the interface (`Map`) instead of an implementation (`HashMap`, for which the order is unpredictable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using HashMap which is not ordered. Try to use a [*List*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or any other ordered data structure - it'll solve your problem.

Comment: You are correct, i outputted to console from within the while loop and it does output it correctly. I assumed hashmap would be ordered by what was put in first. Thanks!

Comment: linkedhashmap will do that as well

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `HashMap` that doesn't gaurante the ordering of elements.

This what the API docs for [java.util.HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) says :

***This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.***

You should rather go for a concrete class that implements `SortedMap` interface which is ***A Map that further provides a total ordering on its keys***.

For example a `TreeMap` will suffice as it implements the `SortedMap` interface.

Comment: Since the purpose is to go over ALL the items in an ordered manner and print them - there's no need for HashMap - a simple LinkedList will do.

Comment: but op wants the players name along with the score, so I thought it.

Comment: a simple string concatenation will do the work (players is a LinkedList):
`players.add(results.getString("username")+ " "+ results.getDouble("balance"));`

Comment: there is a linked hash map that keeps the order